# MongoDB - How to merge output from unwind

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

For example, I have data in a collection like this:

```
db.inventory2.insertMany([
  { "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", price: NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes": [ "S", "M", "L"] },
  { "_id" : 2, "item" : "EFG", price: NumberDecimal("120"), "sizes" : [ ] },
  { "_id" : 3, "item" : "IJK", price: NumberDecimal("160"), "sizes": ["M"] },
])
```

And, when adding `$unwind`, I want to select the item which has `sizes` is not null.

The result after I add `$unwind`:

```
db.inventory2.aggregate( [ { $unwind: { path: "$sizes" } } ] )
```

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "S" }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "M" }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "L" }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "IJK", "price" : NumberDecimal("160"), "sizes" : "M" }
```

My question is, when I add `$unwind`, how to not separate the result item "ABC". My expectation result is like this:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : ["S", "M", "L"] }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "IJK", "price" : NumberDecimal("160"), "sizes" : ["M"] }
```

Thanks before for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understand from your question,  you are trying to filter the document with `sizes` is not an empty array.

You don't need `$unwind` stage but a `$match` stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      sizes: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tCs6iBbE_Ej)

---

Or

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          {
            "$size": "$sizes"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UAMGP6G7WQF)

Answer (score 1):

how about this instead of $unwind:

```
db.inventory2.aggregate([
  {
      $addFields : {
          "sizeCount" : {$size: "$sizes"}
      }
  },
  {$match: {"sizeCount" : {$gt: 0}}},
  {$project: {"sizeCount" : 0}}
])
```